# Html/Css not displaying/loading correctly sometimes, that is occuring without any pattern

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

My website loads correctly most of the time, but without any pattern (that I can recognize) it just bug and load like pure html without styling... Would appreciate any tips or tools to find out what is happening
I will show how it seems when it fails to load and when it loads correctly (tested on Firefox). The website is [www.dinhonesto.com.br](https://dinhonesto.com.br)

The "top left" and "top right" screenshots occur when it fails to load, the "bottom left" and "bottom right" occurs when it loads successfully
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using developer tools in Firefox to see if the css file is getting downloaded?

Comment: isAif I used the firebug but when it bugs it don't show which files are being loaded, when I reload the page is shows but it loads right